# How can I use fork to calculate partial results of a calculation?

Tags: c, function, parallelism, fork

The task that has been given to me is that I have to find all numbers that divide a number (let's call it x) and find out how many times does it divide it.
I **have to use fork** to do the task.
What I have came up with is that I wrote a function which calculates how many times a number divides x and I ran that in a for loop and it works fine.
However I want to "parallelize" this with fork. Is it possible?

My C function looks like this

```
int check_dividers(int *x, int i)
{
  int c = 0;

  if (*x % i == 0)
  {
    do
    {
      c++;
      *x = *x / i;
    } while (*x % i == 0);
  }

  return c;
}
```

I tried spawning a new process to do each calculation and write it to an output file but it just gets messed up.

```
 int i = 2;

  while (i < x && x != 0)
  {
    if (x % i == 0)
    {
      pid_t pid;

      if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
      {
        perror("error during fork");
        exit(0);
      }
      else
      {
        if (pid == 0)
        {
          int num_dividers = check_dividers(&x, i);

          fprintf(out, "%d: %d\n", i, num_dividers);
          fflush(out);
        }
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
```

My output if x = 315

```
3: 2
5: 1
7: 1
21: 1
9: 1
5: 1
15: 1
9: 1
7: 1
63: 1
7: 1
105: 1
15: 1
9: 1
35: 1
45: 1
21: 1
```

Comment: What does the part that forks writes and reads look like?

Comment: The thing is that I haven't really used fork. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Try doing that then and post the troublesome code.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Also use a `for` loop: `for (int i=2; i < x && x != 0; i++) {... }`. It won't help with the `fork`ing, but there is already an answer for that. It will make your code clearer.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the child processes don't exit after their task has been completed.  All processes will be running their own instance of the outer loop.

You need a `exit(0)` after fflush.

You should also `wait` for the children.
You can do it (1) in the end with `while (wait(NULL) != -1);` or (2) after each process with `waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);` after `if ((pid = fork()) < 0) { ... } else { ... }`
You'll need to include `<sys/wait.h>`.

The first option will temporarily cause a lot of zombies but the second removes the parallelism.

Comment: There should also be code to `wait` for the children. Probably not needed for a short lived parent, but it may have highlighted the bug.